# Laravel make arguments optional in a File

Tags: php, laravel

```
<div class="images section clearfix">
    <h4>Images</h4>
    {!! Form::_image("image_id", "Logo", (isset($_tournament))? $_tournament->logo : null) !!}
    {!! Form::_image("image_large_id", "Large Logo", (isset($_tournament))? $_tournament->logoLarge : null) !!}
    {!! Form::_image("image_square_id", "Square Logo", (isset($_tournament))? $_tournament->logoSquare : null) !!}
    @endif
</div>




<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-6">
    <p>
      {!! Form::hidden($name, null, ["id" => $name]) !!}
      @if(isset($image))
        <img width=100 id="{{ $name }}" src="{!! staticFileUrl('img', imagePath($image->folder, $image->filename)) !!}" />
      @else
        <img width=100 id="{{ $name }}" src="" />
      @endif
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#media_select" data-fieldname="{{ $name }}">Select {{ $display_name }}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="clear-media">Clear {{ $display_name }}</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("button#clear-media").click(function() {
  $form_element = $(this).parents("div.form-group");
  $form_element.find("input#{{ $name }}").val(null);
  $form_element.find("img#{{ $name }}").attr("src", "");
});
</script>
```

I got a thrown into a laravel project and I have no experience in PHP so I have no idea to fix this. 
I need to add a default image for these fields and I just wonder is there a way to make all arguments optional `staticFileUrl('img', imagePath($image->folder, $image->filename)` optional so I can write something like this `staticFileUrl('img', imagePath("random string", "other random string")`?

Answer (score 1):

Those already are variables based on the values set in the `$image` model.

If all you need is a default, change the `@else`

```
@if(isset($image))
    <img width="100" id="{{ $name }}" src="{!! staticFileUrl('img', imagePath($image->folder, $image->filename)) !!}" />
@else
    <img width="100" id="{{ $name }}" src="http://www.example.org/your-image.jpg" />
@endif
```

It currently displays nothing if there is no image object. Adding the `src` and an image will display that as your default unless it has an image.